# How to check if the input given by the user is Y or N

Tags: java, if-statement

to summarise it give me any idea or solution on how I could fix it.

I tried what is given in the code below.

```
System.out.print("Want to continue Shopping or end your shopping spree and want the bill for your shopping (answer in Y or N)");
            String end = sc.next();
            if(end =="Y")
                System.out.println("hello");
```

I expect the output hello in the above code, but the actual results are nothing the program just ends.

Comment: Please provide a complete, working code sample and the input you are providing that doesn't work as expected. But in general you should use `String.equals()` to compare Strings in Java, not the `==` operator. In your case you might consider using `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` as well.

Comment: @CrEaTor VR did you tried my solution? If it helped you please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have no idea what your question is about exactly. I can't see any information on which programming language you are using (I suppose Java) or on which operating system you are working.

But I've got an idea what the problem might be: As you are using stdout, I suppose the program happens on a Console or Terminal. And in some environments, the cmd window will close after there program terminated (when working with an IDE like VS Community, which I don't know if you do or not, given no context). If this is the case, "hello" will be printed but you won't see it because the window closes immediately. Try to add some kind of getline at the end and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `sc` is a `Scanner` object.

String comparison must be done with the `equal` method instead of using `==` because by doing that you'll compare the object's referer in the memory instead of the String content, try this:

```
System.out.print("Want to continue Shopping or end your shopping spree and want the bill for your shopping (answer in Y or N)");
String end = sc.next();
if(end.equals("Y")) {
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```